# How to insert Github button images into README.md

Tags: css, image, github

I'm trying to create step-by-step process of a project hosted at Github. Does anybody know a smart way of working with these images? The one below was copy-pasted from Github webpage. That's why the resolution is not so good.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add Images in your README.md file like this

```
[![AltText](ImageLink)](redirectlink)
```

1. **AltText** - The Text which will be appearing if the given image is
   not supported or image link is broken/invalid.
2. **ImageLink** - The Image link that will be shown in the README.md
3. **redirectlink** - The link that will be shown/redirected when someone clicks on the image button

**Example**

```
[![Github](https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png)](https://github.com/)

[<img src="https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png" width="30"/>](https://github.com/)
```

Comment: Dear Sarang, thanks for your answer. However, i was trying to refer to the same image on github.